# Using the <% %> inside a control's parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net, user-controls

I wish to do the following but it doesn't seem possible, was wondering if there is a work around or a way to make it work.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvImCool"
                            runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Some error message <%=//Do something here %>"
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

You can see I am using the `<%= %>` sign in the ErrorMessage parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `<%=%>` is short for:

```
<script runat="server">
Response.Write();
</script>
```

You should be able to see why you can't use them within a server side control.

You should set the property in the code-behind page:

```
rfvImCool.ErrorMessage = "Some error message " + " Do something here";
```

Comment: I didnt realise that's what it was short for thanks for the information.

Comment: Setting the code behind worked like a charm why didn't I think of that, well thanks for the lil bit of knowledge must appreciated. It didn't work within the serverside control.

Comment: Since you didn't know what `<%=%>` is, I'll mention that you should also look up [`<%:%>` (Html Encoding Blocks)](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx) if you're using .Net 4.

Comment: @Brian can't wait to use 4.0 in new projects thanks for great link.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `<%= %>` but you can use the databinding expression `<%# %>` like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvImCool"
                        runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Some error message <%# SomePropertyOrEvalCall %>"
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The contents of `<%# %>` will get called when the control's `DataBind` method is called (typically you would call this on the `Page` and it would propagate down to the child controls.

Comment: Thanks worked is well, but Odeds solution was quicker to implement and he gave the code I needed to.

Comment: Is this a commonly-accepted approach?  It feels kludgey to call DataBind on a control to which no data will be bound, using it merely as a trigger to execute databinding expressions.  (of course, there's probably lots of commonly-accepted approaches that sounded kludgey at first!)

Comment: +1 This is a bit dirty, IMO, but it works well and is faster to implement than mucking with the code-behind if you're doing it for a lot of properties.  There are also a few runtime errors this can solve.  Of course, if you use this trick on a page containing databound controls, you may end up paying for it in controls rendered in unexpected ways and/or in extra database calls, since you're forced to make an "extra" call DataBind.  A good trick, but a bit dangerous.

Comment: @Brian, I completely disagree about this is being dangerous. This is exactly what databinding is for. Personally I don't think anyone should ever use `<%= %>` as that is far more dangerous. Problems should only occur if `DataBind` is called twice, which you can prevent by having a rule that it only be called once on the top-most `Page` control. In addition, you should never be doing database calls within a `DataBind` call itself--all database calls should be done with results assigned to `DataSource` properties before `DataBind` is triggered.

Comment: @Samuel Neff: The dangerous part is that adding a call to `DataBind` on a page that didn't previously have one could potentially change its behavior, or the behavior of child controls that only show up on some pages but not others.  `<%= %>` is generally a much more localized change.  This is usually not a concern though I've had cases where I had to override a control's `DataBind` to be an empty method so that a call to `Page.DataBind()` did not wipe out the custom databinding used by the control.

Comment: @Brian, I see how that could be a problem, but would encourage standardizing on when to call Page.DataBind and calling it on every page even if databinding isn't currently being used and never calling it on a specific control.